# Django Migration, Getting User by Username: You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm running a data migration that parses a python dictionary and creates objects in a database for every object in the dictionary with their respective fields.

The issue is that one of the fields is a user, and the other is a foreign key. When I try and get their objects, I'm met with `django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.`

I know I can probably put `with transaction.atomic()` somewhere, and I've looked at similar questions on StackOverflow but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's my migration:

```
def upload_change_data(apps, schema_editor):
    # Import all required apps
    Change = apps.get_model('changecontrol', 'Change')
    Server = apps.get_model('changecontrol', 'Server')
    User = apps.get_model('auth', 'User')

    # Iterate over every entry in dictionary and add a new change object
    # to a list of all changes
    changes = []
    for page in initial_data:
        for entry in page:
            # Try and find the user that created this object, otherwise
            # skip the object
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=page[entry]['admin'])
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                continue

                # Get the server that this change was for
                computer = Server.objects.get(name=page[entry]['computer'])

                # Append the change object to the list of changes
                changes.append(
                               Change(time=page[entry]['time'],
                                      server=computer,
                                      summary=page[entry]['summary'],
                                      user=user)
                               )
    Change.objects.bulk_create(changes)
```

The error is being thrown specifically at:
`user = User.objects.get(username=page[entry]['admin'])`

Though I'm sure the error would also be thrown at `computer = Server.objects.get(name=page[entry]['computer'])`.

I've tried putting `with transaction.atomic()` before the line in which the error is thrown (and trying to catch an IntegrityError), but to no avail.

Full traceback below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 193, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/leek1j/projects/web_services/changecontrol/migrations/0002_upload_data.py", line 73, in upload_change_data
    user = User.objects.get(username=page[entry]['admin'])
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 374, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 232, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/Users/leek1j/envs/web_services/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 894, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: @KlausD. Added!

Comment: The error might have happened earlier in the same transaction. The query before seems to have failed. If you are using a database server check its log. Or try [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/models/) just before the error!

Comment: @KlausD. Yep. That seems to be it. There was a second python function that ran but I assumed it would have made a separate transaction. Thanks for the help. If you wanna turn that into an answer I can mark it as correct!